# Mercurial print list of commits by author in windows

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Im currently using mercurial on a windows client.

Im using Tortoise HG but there doesn't seems to be any print function.

How can i get a list of commits that i can print?

And i want it by a specified user.

Answer (score 7):

`hg help log` + `hg help revsets` + `hg help templating` if you want to modify output

List of changesets for author X:

- `hg log -u X`
- `hg log -r "user(X)"`

if there are spaces in authors name use `''`:

- `hg log -u 'John Johnson'`